# Unrecognized Selector on Calling allKeys

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm calling the following code on a number of JSON dictionaries within another dictionary (so in this case, `NSDictionary` objects with another `NSDictionary`.

```
-(NSString *)getAllDictionaryValues:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *output=[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    for(NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
    {
        output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@: %@",output, key, [dict objectForKey:key]];
    }
    return output;
}
```

When I run this code, however, I get

```
2014-03-30 01:27:35.565 WebServiceTest[48606:60b] -[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9270230
```

What is wrong about my call to `allKeys`?

Comment: Check if you really sent `NSDictionary` object to your `getAllDictionaryValues:` method

Comment: Show the code where you use `getAllDictionaryValues:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like when you sending message to this function it may be declare your code that `dict` is an `NSDicationay` object (when you call this function) but it not an dictionary may be an array of String or etc that why you getting the exception.

```
-(NSString *)getAllDictionaryValues:(NSDictionary *)dict
```

So first check your `dict` like

```
if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    //is an array
}else if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    //is an dictionary
}else if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
//is an string
}else{
    //or its something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are inputting a string rather than a dictionary object in the calling method

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious. As log said, you tried to call `allKeys` method on `__NSCFString` instance. It means that you sent `NSString` instead of `NSDictionary` to `getAllDictionaryValues:` method.

Answer (score 1):

It means the `dict` object is `NSString` type. You can check the object like this:

```
if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
// dict is NSDictionary type of object
} else if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
// dict is string type of object.
}
```